# Enable python pdb on emacs with virtualenv

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv, pdb

While running pdb within emacs, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313090/2476373) (`python -m pdb myscript.py`) is successful for enabling python pdb on emacs with virtualenv.

The problem is that I need to type it manually after calling `M-x pdb`

How could I edit my .emacs file to use it automatically, without the need to type it manually every time?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mostly a question about how to tell Emacs to do something; the http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ site is better for those questions.