# Debuggin with pdb within a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pdb

I'm developing in python inside a Conda environment. All the packages I add to the environment can be imported successfully when running the "python" binary created under the environment. However, when trying to debug with pdb any of my python scripts I would get ImportError for the very same packages.

For example, after creating a new environment and adding the following packages

```
pip install keras
pip install conection
```

I run the following test.py script

```
import keras
import connexion

print("I have imported keras alright")
print("I have imported connexion alright")

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# for a single-input model with 2 classes (binary):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=784, activation='softmax'))

print("I have defined a keras network alright")
```

This works alright when invoking it the usual way,

```
python test.py  # Works OK
```

but fails when running in debug mode in pdb

```
pdb test.py # ImportError: No module named connexion
```

The question is: how can pdb be properly configured to work with the packages that were installed in the conda environment?

Additional info: while the python binary is indeed in the conda environment

```
which python # returns $HOME/miniconda3/envs/$USER/bin/python
```

pdb seems to always refer to the system version

```
which pdb # returns /usr/bin/pdb
```

Comment: What is the first line (shebang) of `/usr/bin/pdb`?

Comment: Also have a look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734880/getting-pdb-in-emacs-to-use-python-process-from-current-virtualenv?rq=1

Comment: @DeanFenster good point, the shebang is #! /usr/bin/python2.7, while I'm using the Anaconda3 distribution. Still, same issues take place if I instead use pdb3 (shebang #! /usr/bin/python3.4), so the system version of python instead of conda's is being used.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python`  should do the trick

Comment: Exactly, that's it! As per in the linked answer you provided, I just copied pdb3 to my environment, then edited it to use #!/usr/bin/env python as shebang. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @DeanFenster if you write down the answer I will accept it. Or should I write the answer myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy `pdb` executable to your environment, and set the shebang (first line) from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`. If you want this to be the default behavior for any environment (including the system pdb), you can change the shebang only in `/usr/bin/pdb`.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, use `python3 -m pdb <script>` to use pdb with conda and python 3

Comment: This works just as well with python 2, and also does not require you to do any copying and modifying.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!